# CGAL on Codeblock, compiler error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, codeblocks, cgal

I'm trying to run the example "Scale_Space_Surface_Reconstruction_3" from CGAL library on CodeBlocks IDE on Ubuntu platform, as it would be nice
to have the IDE support for code completion and a more automatic configuration process.

I managed to successfully execute it by compiling it with cmake on the terminal window.

However, on CodeBlocks, after creating a new project and copying the code from the example, I get the following error:

`/usr/local/include/CGAL/Scale_Space_Reconstruction_3/Scale_Space_Surface_Reconstruction_Impl_3.h:165:23: error: variable or field 'pca' declared void
Approximation pca( _nn[i]);`

By looking inside the code, I found out that this is due to an undefined Macro `CGAL_EIGEN3_ENABLED`. As my experiment shows, if I define the macro at
pre-processing time, I do not get the same error. That is because, by defining the macro, the type definition `Default::Get< wA,void>::type`, becomes
`Default::Get< wA, Weighted_PCA_approximation_3<Gt>>::type`, and the compiler does not complain any more.

Unfortunately, as a deserved prize for messing with things I do not really understand, I get a segmentation fault at runtime.

**How should I change the compiler options of codeBlocks to make the compilation succeed, and the executable run successfully?**

I have the following include paths:
`/usr/local/lib/CGAL/    /usr/local/include    /usr/include    /usr/include/eigen3.`

I also included the following libraries:
`libCGAL.so, libCGAL_Core.so, libCGAL_ImageIO.so, libgmp.so, libmpfr.so, libtbb.so, libtbbmalloc.so, libtbbmalloc_proxy.so`

Comment: did you try using cmake to generate a codeblock project/file?

Comment: No I did not try to generate the codeblock project/file with cmake. Since I wanted to use codeblock make file built-in feature, I started a new project and copied the code from the examples. However, thanks for the tip I'll try to get some information from the generated code.

Comment: I tried generating the project file with cmake, using the 'Codeblock - Unix Makefiles' generator. However, when I opened the project in Codeblock, it started taking away all the RAM, till the PC became unstable. Though, I could understand that the cmake generated project has a custom makefile. Can I only solve the problem by creating a custom makefile?

Comment: try adding -frounding-math as compiler flag. It should solve the segfault issue.